# my code in code chef is showing NZEC error for this part of code

Tags: python

In codechef this part of my code shows error ?

n=int(input())
l=[]

```
for i in range(n):
    
    l.append(int(input())
```

Comment: Please read about [ask]. First of all make sure your post is properly formatted. Second, if you get an error - please post it

Answer (score 2):

You made an error with brackets, there is 1 missing

correct answer:

```
for i in range(n):

    l.append(int(input()))
```